# while giving string value to integer what is happening?

Tags: c, if-statement, casting

In my C program i assign a string in one integer variable and i print with percentage %s it will print that string with warning integer to pointer without cast and print with %d it print 134513904 then i change my string value and print with %d "134513904" is printing what is this value and how integer variable storing a string value in int variable?

```
enter code here
         #include<stdio.h>
            main()
{
        int a="naveen";
        printf("%d\n",a);
        printf("\n%s\n",a);
        if("naveen")
        {
                printf("hi");
       }
int_point.c: In function ‘main’:
```

int_point.c:22:8: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
  int a="naveen";
        ^
int_point.c:24:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("\n%s\n",a);
  ^
134513920

naveen
hi

Comment: string in an integer variable?

Comment: @Inian yes string stored in integer variable

Comment: it isn't. You have undefined behaviour. Everything your program does is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

The following assigns a *pointer* (not a string) to `s`:

```
const char *s = "navven";
```

That means the following assigns a *pointer* (not a string) to `a`:

```
int a = "naveen";
```

Computers don't really see a difference between a pointer and number. They're both things that fit in their registers. And some people take advantage of that fact. So while the compiler warns you that you are doing something wrong, it still lets you treat the pointer as a number.

So `a` is ends up with the value of the pointer if it were an `int`. That's not safe to do. Not quite. While you can't use an `int` safely, you can use an `intptr_t` safely.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *p1 = "naveen";
    printf("%p %s\n", p1, p1);

    intptr_t i = (intptr_t)p1;
    printf("0x%" PRIxPTR "\n", i);

    const char *p2 = (const char*)i;
    printf("%p %s\n", p2, p2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x51ee878764 naveen
0x51ee878764
0x51ee878764 naveen
```